# line-rectangle collision detection

Tags: collision-detection

I have one line (two point (x,y) (x1,y1)) and a rectangle with focus point (rx,ry). I need help to find out collision point between line and rectangle, an example in C++ will be help.

Comment: it is a rectangle with centered point (rx, ry)

Comment: what about width, height, or rotation?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585525/how-to-find-the-intersection-point-between-a-line-and-a-rectangle

Comment: @ paxdiablo that link is for a box that is centred on one end point of the line. That's not the case in this question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see how you can represent a rectangle with just a "focus point". You'll need either the two corner points or one corner point with a width/height/rotation set of data.

However, once you *have* a rectangle, I would simply break it down into four lines and do the intercept checks between each of those four lines and the line you want to check against.

Doing a search on SO for "line intersection" turns up numerous questions, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect), which seems promising. In fact, searching for "line rectangle intersection" gives you [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585525/how-to-find-the-intersection-point-between-a-line-and-a-rectangle), which seems to be *exactly* what you're after.

Comment: The OP might also want to detect the case where the line was fully contained within the rectangle, which would require a separate check.

Answer (score 3):

Theres a lot of information out there about interectioning shapes.
http://www.geometrictools.com/LibFoundation/Intersection/Intersection.html is probably a very good starting spot. In fact it contains C++ code for line-rectangle intersection. And its by Dave Eberly who is fairly well known in the computer graphics world.

Having said that what I'd do if I *needed* my own algorithm is something like this:

1. Find the equation of the line containing the line-segment as a x + b y - 1 = 0;
2. evaluate f(x) = a x + b y - 1 for each vertex of the rectangle
3. If all corners are > 0 or all are < 0 you have no possible intersection.
4. Intersections can only occur on edges with one vertex having f(x)>0 and the other having f(x)< 0. So perform a line-segment to line-segment intersection with all such edges and the original line-segment.

This should work for arbitrary polygons. And so rotated rectangles wont be a problem.

If you need to speed things up a bit you can improve the rejection criteria in 3, by using axis-aligned bounding rectangles for the line segment and the rectangle.