# Ray/rectangle intersection in JS

Tags: javascript, geometry, intersection

I am really not able to create a "point" (straight with an angle starting at a specific point) rectangle intersection to find the intersecting points (using JS). *Just found out it's called "ray", so I edited the title.*

I read so much about it and found many solutions for line/line intersections and line/rectangle intersections etc.

In my case, I don't have a line with start and endpoint, but a point with a given angle from which there needs to be a line till the intersection point.

Later on, the line should only be visible in the inner auf the rectangle, that's why I need the intersection. The rectangle is always axis-aligned.

I have no idea how to get that intersection because of the many cases (point in rectangle, point out of the rectangle, negative values). And I never worked with vectors.

I created an image to make it clearer:

[image: Example]

Any ideas on how to get the intersection points?

Probably I have to start testing every line of the rectangle against my straight line. But I even don't know how to check that...

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I have to rush off, so I can only point you the right way: Sine, cosine, and triangles. Here's what the triangles look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/clv7Q.jpg

Comment: Quick question based on your image: are the rectangles always axis aligned?

Comment: More about sine and cosine and how they relate to this: https://www.mathsisfun.com/sine-cosine-tangent.html

Comment: @MichaelBeeson
Yes, the rectangle is always axis aligned!

Comment: As you're basicly working with lines (rectangle is four separate lines), you can create equations for the lines (`y = kx + b`) using trigonometric functions, then an intersection occurs at `Rect(x) - Line(x) === 0`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if line segment intersects a rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203760/how-to-check-if-line-segment-intersects-a-rectangle)

Answer (score 0):

```
An algebraic solution:
```

Assume the window to be `[0, W]x[0, H]`. We write the equation of the half line as

```
X = x + t.u
Y = y + t.v
```

where `t ≥ 0`.

Let us assume `u, v ≥ 0` for now. We want to solve the inequations

```
0 ≤ t
0 ≤ x + t.u ≤ W
0 ≤ y + t.v ≤ H
```

or

```
    0 ≤ t.u.v
- x.v ≤ t.u.v ≤ (W - x).v
- y.u ≤ t.u.v ≤ (H - y).u
```

There is a solution iff

```
t0 < t1
```

where

```
t0= max(0, - x.v, - y.u)
t1= min((W - x).v, (H - y).u).
```

The intersection points are obtained by plugging the values of `t0/(u.v)`, `t1/(u.v)` in the equation of the half-line.

You have to repeat that discussion for all signs of `u`, `v`, including `0`. There are 9 combinations, but this is manageable.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, but as I never worked with vectors I don't really understand anything of that. :-D And most important I have to translate it to JS.
How would it be in a cartesian coordinate system?

Comment: @Timo: this *is* in Cartesian coordinates, and there are no vectors.

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry, I really don't get it. Especially how to do it in JavaScript then.