# Find list of pixels between two points

Tags: javascript, list, object, javascript-objects, p5.js

I'm currently programming my first game in JavaScript, and I've never technically learned JavaScript, I'm more fluent with Python.

Anyway, I need to find a way to make a list of all the pixels between two points on a straight horizontal line. I would then use the list to reference whether the user's character is touching any of the pixels to trigger a screen change.

It would be something like

```
pixels = []
(Function here to add the pixels to the list)
    For pixel in pixels
         If (dist(object.x, object.y, pixel.x, 0) < 1) {
            object.x = start point on new screen
            Object.y =
```

Does this make any sense? I'm sorry I'm bad at explaining things but I could use the help.

Comment: I'm using mobile so I'm sorry my formatting sucks

Comment: There is no need to generate this list. If your character is a rectangle, you can compute if the line intersects the rectangle. If not, you can check for every pixel in the character if its in the line made from those 2 points

Comment: how do I check if the line intersects the rectangle?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203760/how-to-check-if-line-segment-intersects-a-rectangle

Comment: thank you so much for your help

Comment: You could also have a look at the [p5.collide2D](https://github.com/bmoren/p5.collide2D) library

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly don't want to test intersection this way. This is going to require many more steps than just doing standard line-rectangle collision detection.

I recommend googling something like "line rectangle intersection" or "line rectangle collision detection" for a ton of results, including:

- [line-rectangle collision detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368211/line-rectangle-collision-detection)
- [How to check if line segment intersects a rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203760/how-to-check-if-line-segment-intersects-a-rectangle)
- [How to find the intersection point between a line and a rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585525/how-to-find-the-intersection-point-between-a-line-and-a-rectangle)
- [Line intersection with AABB Rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746274/line-intersection-with-aabb-rectangle)
- [How to test if a line segment intersects an axis-aligned rectange in 2D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99353/how-to-test-if-a-line-segment-intersects-an-axis-aligned-rectange-in-2d)
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111100/intersection-of-a-line-and-a-rectangle