# Is it possible to detect intersection of CGMutablePathRef and CGRect ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite with its bounding box and I want to detect the intersection of it with a CGMutablePathRef. How would I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no readily available solution for that. It also depends on what features of CGPath you are using. If it's just a series of points, you can use a regular [line with rectangle intersection test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585525/how-to-find-the-intersection-point-between-a-line-and-a-rectangle).

Everything else (eg bezier curve and rectangle intersection) is going to be **very** complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I indeed do not have a curve but a hexagon shape. Do I have to create these lines separate from the hexagon or are they handled as separate lines anyway ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a pure rectangular comparison, you can use `CGPathGetBoundingBox` to obtain the path's bounding box and then use `CGRectIntersectsRect` to determine if the intersection occurs.

Comment: This is useful too, thank you, but for me it is just a temporary solution as I do not want to detect the path's bounding box, but rather its proper shape.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on performance needs, draw into a 1-bit deep bitmap, clipping to the CGRect. Then scan for a pixel. (This technique tends to be more appropriate for testing to a point.)

Comment: This approach also appeals to me, thank you very much, I'll try it out.