# Calculate intersect point between arc and line

Tags: java, geometry

I want to calculate the intersect point between arc and line. I have all the data for line and arc.

For line : start and and end point.
For arc : start/end point, start/end angle, radius and center point.

I have attach here one image. In this below image I have draw one arc and line where line intersect the arc.

So now I want to find the intersect point. Please give me some algorithm or idea or if any available code.

[image]

Comment: Honestly! I googled two similar questions on math stackexchange in a few seconds. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228841/how-do-i-calculate-the-intersections-of-a-straight-line-and-a-circle and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078578/how-to-find-coordinates-of-a-point-on-intersection-of-arc-and-line

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the intersection point between a line and a rectangle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585525/how-to-find-the-intersection-point-between-a-line-and-a-rectangle)

Comment: @WeatherVane: the solutions in these two links do not address the issue of the arc delimiting interval, or address it poorly.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?  It's as valid a question on StackOverflow as any other.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean line *segment* instead of line? A line doesn't have a start and end point.

Answer (score 4):

Let's define an arc and a line:

Arc:

- xa=X-coordinate
- ya=Y-coordinate
- a1=starting angle (smaller angle)
- a2=ending angle (greater angle)
- r=radius

Line:

- x1=first X-coordinate
- x2=second X-coordinate
- y1=first Y-coordinate
- y1=second Y-coordinate

From that you can calculate:

- dx=x2-x1
- dy=y2-y1
- al=arctan(dy/dx) (Angle of the line)

The arc and the line won't intersect when al < a1 or al > a2 or, in other words, the angle of the line isn't between the angles of the arc.
The equations for an intersection are as follows:

- xa+r*cos(al)=x1+c*dx
- ya+r*sin(al)=y1+c*dy

where c (0 < c <= 1)is the variable we're looking for. Specifically:

- (xa+r * cos(al)-x1)/dx=c
- (ya+r * sin(al)-y1)/dy=c

The intersection point is therefore at **(x1+c * dx),(y1+c * dy)**

This algorithm only works when the arc and the line have one single intersection. If the line goes through the arc two times then it won't register any intersection.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This answer really helped me. 

xa=X-coordinate
ya=Y-coordinate

In the above line what does it mean xa, ya, and coordinate means arc coordinate?

Comment: Calculated value for c its showing out of range (0 to 1).

Comment: xa and ya are the coordinates of the arcs center point. If c is greater then 1, then there is no intersection because the line stops before crossing the arc. If c is negative, then you propably made a mistake somewhere, most likely during the calculation of dx and dy.

Comment: This assumes that the line goes through the center, doesn't it ?

Comment: I wrote the algorithm same as the above but I am not getting the result properly. Value of C , showing sometime between 0 -1, sometimes greater then 1 or less then 0.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shiladittya/w9f52dt5/ 
In the above link I post my code for calculating value of c and intersecting point. Program is not running. I just posted it for shape my problem with you. The problem is I am not getting the correct value of c and intersect point. Has anyone got an idea where I am going wrong either in my maths or elsewhere? Thank you.

Comment: I assume that the arc is drawn counterclockwise from the starting angle to the end angle. Please clarify this.

Comment: Why are you dividing by dx to obtain cx if you then multiply cx by dx to obtain the x coordinate of the intersecting point? These two operations cancel each other out.

Comment: I think there are some ambiguous order of operations in your expressions, notable for (xa+r * cos(al)-x1)/dx=c
(ya+r * sin(al)-y1)/dy=c

Also it would be nice to give the names of these functions for further research (if they exist)