# Check line and arc intersected or not

Tags: math, geometry, line

I am searching for an algorithm which can shows line and arc intersected or not. 
For line I have start and end point and for arc I have start, end and center point. I also have start and end angle of an ARC.

[image]

As you can see in the above image I have draw an arc and line where as both are intersected. How to calculate that intersected or not?

I found one link which can shows the intersection between line and circle [Circle Line Intersection points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053061/circle-line-intersection-points) but in my case I have line and arc. Even I also have another question what is best way to calculate the intersection between two ARC?

Any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006155/calculate-intersect-point-between-arc-and-line   i guess if solution exists,  then they intersect

Answer (score 0):

By equating the parametric equations of the line and the circle,

```
X = Sx + t SEx = Cx + R cos(u)
Y = Sy + t SEy = Cy + R sin(u)
```

which can be written

```
 t SEx + CSx = R cos(u)
 t SEy + CSy = R sin(u)
```

You eliminate `u` by adding the squares

```
(SEx² + SEy²) t² + 2 (SEx.CSx + SEy.CSy) t + CSx² + CSy² - R² = 0
```

Solve the quadratic equation for `t` and check `0<t<1` (there can be two solutions).

Then compute `X` and `Y` and from these

```
tan(u) = (Y - Cy) / (X - Cx)
```

(use `atan2`). Then check that `u` is in the valid range.

---

For two arcs,

```
C0x + R0 cos(u) = C1x + R1 cos(v)
C0y + R0 sin(u) = C1y + R1 sin(v)
```

or

```
Dx + R0 cos(u) = R1 cos(v)
Dy + R0 sin(u) = R1 sin(v)
```

Summing the squares,

```
2R.Dx cos(u) + 2R.Dy sin(u) + Dx² + Dy² + R0² = R1²
```

Divide by `2R√(Dx²+Dy²)` to put in the form

```
c cos(u) + s sin(u) = e
```

which can be written as

```
cos(u-w) = e, where tan(w) = s/c
```

Then

```
u = w ± arcos(e)
```

gives you the potential intersections.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty: I'd prefer that you do it and publish. SO isn't a free code factory.

Comment: Could you please explain the variable which are used so that it will be easy to implement for me?

Comment: S start, E end, C center. SE is the 2D vector from S to E. R: radius. x and y indexes should be obvious.

Comment: What is the u and v for arc? and also Dx, Dy

Comment: They are the parameters of the parametric equation (read about the parametric equation of a circle); their range is the angular extent of the arc. Dx and Dy are obvious from the equations.

Comment: It would be really help full for me if you give some example with real value.

Comment: No, you choose your data and try to match your values to my notation, as far as you can go.

Comment: For which value of t line and arc intersected or not?

Comment: SE vector means (E-S) ?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty: yes, what else ?

Comment: (SEx² + SEy²) t² + 2 (SEx.CSx + SEy.CSy) t + CSx² + CSy² - R² = 0 calculated t value from this equation but its also showing NaN value.

Comment: Finally I able work the above equation. But I have one question after calculating t value from above equation how to check line or intersected or not?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty: I wrote it: 0<t<1.

Comment: I tried with it, but sometimes got correct result or sometimes wrong.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty: draw a graphical representation of your test cases to ease troubleshooting.