# How do I break the game when objects collide on Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I made this small game similar to flappy birds, where one can use to fly up and down using the mouse and keyboard.

I won't be posting the full code because it's a university project and I don't want to get caught for any possible plagiarism.

What I did was, I used two objects:

A rectangle as the **bird**:

```
r= rectangle('Position', pos, 'curvature', [0.99,0.1], 'FaceColor', 'r', 'EraseMode','xor');
```

Thick lines to represent the walls:

```
line([ 100 100], [10 400], 'color', 'm', 'LineWidth', 10, 'EraseMode', 'background')
```

---

**My problem:**

The problem is that the **bird** moves through the walls, as if the walls were transparent. As you can imagine, I want to break the game and show something like "**game over**", when the bird hits the wall (not go through them). How do I make it such that my game breaks when the bird (object 1) collides with the walls (other objects)?

**Thank You Very Much for reading my question!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Mapping Toolbox installed, it provides a function called [`polyxpoly`](http://mathworks.com/help/map/ref/polyxpoly.html) that allows you to intersect [polylines](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain), so you can find the intersection of the whole rectangle against every wall, and you will not have to worry about splitting every edge of the rectangle.

Here you have a full working example of a collision with one wall:

```
% Bird (rectangle).
% Position.
xr = 30;
yr = 100;

% Length of rectangle edges.
deltaxr = 10;
deltayr = 10;

% Vector for rectangle object.
vr = [xr, yr, deltaxr, deltayr];

% Bird polyline.
a = [xr, yr];
b = [xr + deltaxr, yr];
c = [xr + deltaxr, yr + deltayr];
d = [xr, yr + deltayr];
r = [a; b; c; d];

% Wall (line).
% Wall polyline.
l = [40 0; 40 105];

% Draw objects.
r1 = rectangle('Position',vr,'LineWidth',2);
line(l(:,1), l(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','r');
axis equal;

% Find intersections.
[xi,yi] = polyxpoly(r(:,1),r(:,2),l(:,1),l(:,2));

% Are there any intersections? If so, GAME OVER.
if ~isempty(xi)
    % Stop the game and display GAME OVER.
    text(xr-20,yr-20,'GAME OVER','Color','b','FontSize', 20);
end
```

You can try with different positions of the bird to test the collision detection:

[image: Collision detection flappy bird]

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to use an intersection algorithm to check whether there is an intersection of one of the wall-lines (check it four times) with the rectangle. The rectangle basically also consists of 4 lines, that means you should check the 4 rectangle-lines against the four wall-lines (if you use a line-line-intersection algorithm).

E.g. check this topic:
[How to find the intersection point between a line and a rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585525/how-to-find-the-intersection-point-between-a-line-and-a-rectangle)

It's basically a simple mathematical equation to solve, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection.