# Creating line between two objects in svg

Tags: html, svg

How to create a line/path between two objects. Start and end point of path/line should not begin/end at the center of the respective object. Below i'm attaching the screenshot of sample. I need to calculate the logic to find the red line at any position. Black line is wrong one.

[image]

And it is purely based on SVG not html elements.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to do this for svg, just change objects order. I'm use [raphael.js](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) for rule svg. It have functions `el.insertAfter(); el.insertBefore(); el.toBack(); el.toFront();` for control objects order.

Comment: Thanks @imbearr. Is there any way to do without any library.?

Comment: Just readd/append the ones you want at the front to its parent I think (eg obj 1 & 3), that will place them later in the DOM, so the line will appear behind those objects.

Comment: @lan Thanks for your idea. But the problem was i need to implement arrow at the end of the red line using svg marker. in that case this idea wont work. :(

Comment: @VijayBaskaran, you need to found intersection point of two lines. There you can use [math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection) or raphael js library function `Raphael.pathIntersection(first_path,second_path)`.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution without using any library based on the given below URL's.

URL 1: [How to find the intersection point between a line and rectangel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585525/how-to-find-the-intersection-point-between-a-line-and-a-rectangle)

URL 2: [Calculating the intersection of two lines](https://gist.github.com/PAEz/a4dc5742d4443e54e4ad)