# Simulating Light (Point Source) in 2D Room

Tags: d3.js, svg, lighting

I am trying to simulate an omnidirectional light source in a 2D room.  I would like to set up a room and have "light" propagate from a point source, stopping only when it reaches a wall.  The result is shadows will be cast where the light cannot reach.  The below picture shows the problem with several point sources

[image]

I am implementing this in [D3 JS](https://d3js.org/) as part of a game based around the [art gallery problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem).

I am struggling to come up with a data structure suitable for allowing this simulation and animation.  I imagine a circle radiates out from the source, splitting into arcs whenever it encounters a wall?  **Is there a way to do this without simulating lots of individual light beams?**

Comment: Do you really need SVG output?  I seems like it would be a lot simpler to implement this on a Canvas. For each pixel work out which light sources it can see.  Perhaps it may not be fast enough to run in real time. But you may not need that.  Or if you need SVG, you could use polygons for the walls and generate an `<image>` for the lit background.

Comment: D3/SVG is not a requirement at all, it was just a first thought for polygon based animation/etc.  The paradigm you have proposed (pixel by pixel line of sight) is actually better than anything I have come up with yet.  Thanks!

Comment: I imagine it would still be possible to animate the circular light propagation by spiraling outwards from the point source, as opposed to traversing over the rows of pixels?

Comment: Assuming your "gallery" has walls like the example, then each pixel is just 36 calls to a [line/rectangle intersect function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585525/how-to-find-the-intersection-point-between-a-line-and-a-rectangle/31254199#31254199) (4 lights x 9 rectangular walls).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think `d3` will help here, besides drawing the SVG. On the theoretical side, `<circle>` elements have defined radii, which means that they *will* curve at the circumference. Arcs will do the same. The art gallery problem deals with polygonal spaces and circles are (arguably) not polygons.

On the practical side, if you are going to use `d3`, I would instead recommend making `<polygon>` elements. From your picture, it looks as though each 'light' covers at least one room, and the points of a `polygon` can match the coordinates of the walls. Where the lights extend out into other rooms, they look to be, from the dotted lines, triangles in most cases. Where the colors overlap, `d3` can help because SVG elements are allowed `fill` properties with `alpha` components.

```
d3.select('svg').append('polygon')
    .attr('fill', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)')
    .attr('d', foo);
```

That will draw a polygon with a semi-transparent red color.

*However*, `d3` won't help you figure out the coordinates of these lights. IMHO you could do this with a search algorithm which starts at a 'light source' and emanates out in a linear fashion checking for walls. When it finds a wall, it takes the coordinates of that 'stop' point and adds it to the path of the `polygon`. When the `polygon` draws, the colors will overlap and appear to be light sources.

Comment: I should also add that this question is pretty theoretical and probably doesn't belong on SO

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I suspected that SO may not be the most appropriate place either.  Are there better suited SE forums?

Comment: In a perfect world, some sort of Computational Geometry SE site would be best, but in lieu I would guess either [Theoretical CS](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) or maybe [Code Golf & Puzzles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). You can always [start your own](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) too. IMO seems like a good question for CS/Math professors or a challenge for co-workers